# Two solutions for a 4-velocity component given 3 other components?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, symmetry, time-reversal-symmetry

## The Setup

Suppose I know, in some particular coordinate system, three components of the four-velocity vector $u^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$. For this question I'm going to assume the known components are the spatial components $u^{i}$ with $i = \{1,2,3\}$.

I then use the constraint
$$-\epsilon = g_{\mu \nu}u^\mu u^\nu,$$

where $\epsilon = c^2$ for timelike and $\epsilon = 0$ for null particles, to find the value of $u^0$. I begin by expanding the above Einstein sum and rearranging,

$$0 = g_{00}(u^0)^2 + 2g_{i0}u^iu^0 + g_{ij}u^iu^j + \epsilon.$$

Noticing that this is quadratic in $u^0$, I can solve using the quadratic formula:

$$u^0 = \frac{-2g_{i0}u^i \pm \sqrt{(2g_{i0}u^i)^2 - 4g_{00}(g_{ij}u^iu^j + \epsilon)}}{2g_{00}}$$

## The Problem

From the above equation, it seems there are two solutions for $u^0$.

Specifically, in the case that $g_{i0} \neq 0$ (such as the Kerr metric in Boyer-Lindquist coordinates), the equation for $u^0$ implies two solutions with differing magnitude.

I had previously interpreted the two solutions of $u^0$ in the Minkowski metric (where $g_{i0} = 0$ and so $u^0_{(1)} = -u^0_{(2)}$) as being the forward-in-time and backwards-in-time descriptions of the same trajectory. This makes sense as their magnitudes are the same and their signs are different, and essentially is a statement of time-reversal symmetry.

In the $g_{i0} \neq 0$ case, not only can the magnitudes of the two solutions be different, it's conceivable from looking at the equation that there could exist metrics where both solutions to $u^0$ are positive, both solutions are negative, or even a situation where there are no real solutions, making my statement about time-reversal symmetry clearly incorrect.

Also, we can always move to a local frame $S{'}$ where our metric is Minkowski. in these coordinates, the $u^0{'}$ solutions are equal and opposite - so there's definitely something weird going on in coordinates where $g_{i0} \neq 0$.

My questions:

1. Am I wrong about the time-reversal symmetry being the reason for $\pm u^0$ when $g_{i0}= 0$?
2. Can there indeed be a metric for which both solutions of $u^0$ have the same sign?
3. Can there indeed be a metric for which there are no real solutions of $u^0$?

Feel free to give answers in math-heavy language if you need to (manifolds, chart mappings, etc.).

**EDIT**: One more question I forgot to mention.

4. what is the interpretation of the two different values of $||u^0||$ in the $g_{i0}\neq 0$ case?

Answer (score 0):

1. That's correct.
2. That's incorrect. In your example above you also get different signs for the two solutions, which is obvious from the $-2g_{i0} u^i \pm \sqrt{(2g_{i0} u^i)^2-{...}}$ so you have to chose the positive solution.
3. Only if you chose unphysical values for the other components, for example if the local velocity is higher than the speed of light, then you have to switch the sign of ${\rm d}s$ in order to describe hypothetical tachyons.

Comment: I added a fourth question since yesterday. I can't seem to get agreeing results for 2.

I just checked by putting numbers into the Kerr metric. For a test particle on an equatorial trajectory at theta = pi/2, I can find values of the angular velocity which produce two different but same-sign solutions for the 0th component of the four velocity. These solutions happen close to the Schwarzchild radius and are both nagative if the particle orbit is in the same direction as the Black Hole's rotation and positive if the orbit is opposite.

Comment: If you randomly put in numbers you have to make sure that the gtφ component has the same sign as the gtt component of the metric tensor. If you want to make sure that your initial conditions are physical use #4, code 2 at http://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=230#p230  to check what local 3-velocity relative to a ZAMO your 4-velocity components give. If the 3-velocity is larger than 1 or imaginary your input is unphysical.